# How can I persistent disable left menu in Nautilus (F9)?

Tags: nautilus, gui, usability

When I press F9 left panel hiding, but only before Nautilus restart.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `dconf-editor` from Software Center
2. Launch `dconf-editor`
3. In the left panel, select `org`
4. Then, in the left panel, select `gnome`
5. Then, in the left panel, select `nautilus`
6. Then, in the left panel, select `window-state`
7. In the right panel uncheck `start-with-sidebar`